Can´t use fbox with prooftree
Why do I get an error when I try fo use \fbox around a prooftree? Removing the \fbox works fine. Bussproofs is not compatible with \fbox?
Thanks in advance,
Marcus.
\documentclass {scrbook}
\usepackage {bussproofs}
\newcommand {\lbl} [1]{\LeftLabel{\scriptsize{$(#1)$}}}
\begin {document}

\fbox {

\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC {$x: \sigma \in \Gamma$}
\lbl{var}
\UnaryInfC {$\Gamma \vdash x: \sigma$}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash N: \sigma$}
\lbl{appl}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash MN: \tau$}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma, x: \sigma \vdash M: \tau$}
\lbl{abst}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \lambda x: \sigma.M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
\end{prooftree}

}

\end {document}


You cannot use vertical material inside a horizontal box like \mbox or \fbox unless you add an explicit vertical box, e.g.:
\documentclass {scrbook}
\usepackage {bussproofs}
\newcommand {\lbl} [1]{\LeftLabel{\scriptsize{$(#1)$}}}
\begin {document}

\noindent\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}{%
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC {$x: \sigma \in \Gamma$}
\lbl{var}
\UnaryInfC {$\Gamma \vdash x: \sigma$}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash N: \sigma$}
\lbl{appl}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash MN: \tau$}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma, x: \sigma \vdash M: \tau$}
\lbl{abst}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \lambda x: \sigma.M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
\end{prooftree}%
}}

\end {document}


Note, that I've also removed unwanted spaces and paragraphs (empty lines).
BTW: Using a frame package, i.e., tcolorbox could be useful for frames like this:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\lbl}[1]{\LeftLabel{\scriptsize{$(#1)$}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC {$x: \sigma \in \Gamma$}
\lbl{var}
\UnaryInfC {$\Gamma \vdash x: \sigma$}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash N: \sigma$}
\lbl{appl}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash MN: \tau$}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma, x: \sigma \vdash M: \tau$}
\lbl{abst}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \lambda x: \sigma.M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
\end{prooftree}%
\end{tcolorbox}

\end {document}



It is the paragraph breaks and implicit list (used by prooftree) which cause the issue. If you box the content first, you can use \fbox{}. For example, you could use a minipage.
\documentclass {scrbook}
\usepackage {bussproofs}
\newcommand {\lbl} [1]{\LeftLabel{\scriptsize{$(#1)$}}}
\begin {document}

\fbox {%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{prooftree}
      \AxiomC {$x: \sigma \in \Gamma$}
      \lbl{var}
      \UnaryInfC {$\Gamma \vdash x: \sigma$}
    \end{prooftree}
    \begin{prooftree}
      \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
      \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash N: \sigma$}
      \lbl{appl}
      \BinaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash MN: \tau$}
    \end{prooftree}
    \begin{prooftree}
      \AxiomC{$\Gamma, x: \sigma \vdash M: \tau$}
      \lbl{abst}
      \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \lambda x: \sigma.M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
    \end{prooftree}
  \end{minipage}%
}

\end {document}

Another option would be to use something like a tcolorbox, which would give you a lot more flexibility in terms of styling.
\documentclass {scrbook}
\usepackage {bussproofs}
\newcommand {\lbl} [1]{\LeftLabel{\scriptsize{$(#1)$}}}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin {document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC {$x: \sigma \in \Gamma$}
    \lbl{var}
    \UnaryInfC {$\Gamma \vdash x: \sigma$}
  \end{prooftree}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
    \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash N: \sigma$}
    \lbl{appl}
    \BinaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash MN: \tau$}
  \end{prooftree}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{$\Gamma, x: \sigma \vdash M: \tau$}
    \lbl{abst}
    \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \lambda x: \sigma.M: \sigma\rightarrow\tau$}
  \end{prooftree}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end {document}


